# How to assign values to existed Series with multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a `Series` as following:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], ['x', 'y']], names=['u', 'v'])

In [3]: ser = pd.Series(range(4), index=index)

In [4]: ser
Out[4]: 
u  v
A  x    0
   y    1
B  x    2
   y    3
dtype: int64
```

And I want to change the first two values from a existed `Series` with index `['x', 'y']`:

```
In [5]: ser.loc['A'] = pd.Series([100, 202], index=['x', 'y'])

In [6]: ser
Out[6]: 
u  v
A  x    NaN
   y    NaN
B  x    2.0
   y    3.0
dtype: float64

In [7]: pd.__version__
Out[7]: u'0.21.0'
```

But the result is out of my expectation. What is the right way to solve this problem?

**EDIT**
@jezrael 's  solution works. However, that confused me very much. Since both `ser.loc['A']` and `ser['A']` seems the same. Is there anything I missed?

```
In [7]: ser['A']
Out[7]: 
v
x    100
y    202
dtype: int64

In [8]: ser.loc['A']
Out[8]: 
v
x    100
y    202
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Definitely not an answer, but note that `ser['A'] = pd.Series([100, 202], index=['x', 'y'])` works (in 0.20.3).

Comment: Also, similar issues with MultiIndex seem quite common, eg.: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10440 https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12343 https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working set only by `MutliIndex Series` in `0.21.0` :

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['aaa'], ['x', 'y']])

ser.loc['A'] =  pd.Series([100, 202], index=mux)
print (ser)
u  v
A  x    100
   y    202
B  x      2
   y      3
dtype: int64
```

Also working solution from [comment of Michał Politowski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47413345/how-to-assign-values-to-existed-series-with-multiindex/47413576#comment81780606_47413345):

```
ser['A'] = pd.Series([100, 202], index=['x', 'y'])
```